How can I pass the information from inside a "socket.on" listener to a pinia data store?
I am making a data store, the data store listens to a server using "socket.on", I can see from the console that the data correctly arrives in the "socket.on".  However, when I try to call an action within the "socket.on" I get this error:  useSolarFieldData.updateData is not a function in the following code:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

export const useMyStoreData = defineStore({
  id: "useMyData",
  state: () => ({
    azi_1: null,
    azi_2: null,
    azi_3: null,
    date: null,
  }),

  actions: {
    updateData(data) {
      this.azi_1 = data.azi_1;
      this.azi_2 = data.azi_2;
      this.azi_3 = data.azi_3;
      this.date = data.date;
    },
  },
});

socket.on("dynamic_values", (data) => {

  console.log("Data received from socket:", data); 

  useMyStoreData.updateData(data);

  console.log("Store updated:", useMyStoreData); 
});

export default useMyStoreData;`

I tried to define the values directly into the socket.on listenner:
socket.on("dynamic_values", (data) => {
  console.log("Data received from socket:", data); // Console log added

  useSolarFieldData.azimuth = data.azimuth;
  useSolarFieldData.elevation = data.elevation;
  useSolarFieldData.DNI = data.DNI;
  useSolarFieldData.date = data.date;
  console.log("Store updated:", useSolarFieldData);

});
I can see the values being updated in the console logs but they are not reactive, they are not updated in the store neither and as soon as I call any function within socket.on, it returns to me the "is not a function" error.

useSolarFieldData is composable function and not store object, use it the same way as in components

First of all, you shouldn't export useMyStoreData immediately, using the export keywork along with the declaration of the store. This way javascript will make the store available for imports, but unavailable to be used within the same file/context (without importing it). Then, you should call updateData on an instance of useMyStoreData, which can only be obtained inside a setup function of a Vue component. Something like this should work:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

const useMyStoreData = defineStore({
    id: "useMyData",
    state: () => ({
        azi_1: null,
        azi_2: null,
        azi_3: null,
        date: null,
    }),

    actions: {
        updateData(data) {
            this.azi_1 = data.azi_1;
            this.azi_2 = data.azi_2;
            this.azi_3 = data.azi_3;
            this.date = data.date;
        }
    }
});

const vueComponent = {
 setup() {
    const store = useMyStoreData();

    socket.on("dynamic_values", (data) => {
      console.log("Data received from socket:", data); 
      store.updateData(data);
      console.log("Store updated:", store); 
    });

    return {
      // Return any data or methods you want to use in your template
    };
 }
};

export { useMyStoreData, vueComponent };


"This way javascript will make the store available for imports, but unavailable to be used within the same file/context" - this is not true. This results in redundant named export but doesn't prevent it from being used. Declaring a component in the same module as store is bad design. "which can only be obtained inside a setup" - there's no such limitation, store function isn't regular composable
